# Web Server Plug-ins for IBM WebSphere Application Server v9.0 extra HTTP headers

Tags: websphere

How to disable Web Server Plug-ins for IBM WebSphere Application Server v9.0 from passing following HTTP headers to origin server?

```
$WSXCTCONTEXTID: YJUIhwqmKBkA4ADUj28AAAAA
$WSIS: false
$WSSC: http
$WSPR: HTTP/1.1
$WSRA: 10.0.0.1
$WSRH: 10.0.0.1
$WSSN: 10.0.0.1
$WSSP: 8815
_WS_HAPRT_WLMVERSION: -1
```

Comment: what's the goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They can't be disabled and can't otherwise be prevented.

The only configuration possible in this area relates to how similar headers **received** by the Plugin, which is "RemoveSpecialHeaders" (default true) in plugin-cfg.xml

Comment: Is there a way to suppress it before sending to origin server?